# My Ajax not workin

Tags: javascript, ajax

I started to learn Ajax today. 
And I tried to do some practices by following step by step how to use AJAX but unfortunaly it's not working and I dont know where's the problem since I don't get any warning in console.log.

I have an example.xml in my root folder that i try to get data from.

Here's what I did.
Thanks!

```js
  function getXMLHttpRequest(){
 var xhr = null;
    
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest || window.ActiveXObject){
     if(window.ActiveXobject){
         try{
             xhr = new ActiveXobject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }catch(e){
             xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
        }else{
         xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    
    }else{
     alert("Votre navigateur ne supporte pas l'objet XMLHttpRequest");
    }
    
    return xhr;
}


function request(callback){

 var xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();
    
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if(xhr.readyStae == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)){
         callback(xhr.responseXML);
        }
    }
    
    xhr.open("GET", "example.xml", true);
    xhr.send(null);    
}

    function readData(oData){
     var node = oData.getElementsByTagName("soft");
        var ul = document.createElement("ul");
        var li, content;
        
        for(let i = 0; i < node.length; i++){
        
         li = document.createElement("li");      
            content = document.createTextNode(node[i].getAttribute("name"));
            li.appendChild(content);
            ul.appendChild(li);
        }


        document.getElementById("output").appendChild(ul);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>ajax</title>
</head>
<body>
 <p>
  <button onclick="request(readData);">Afficher les données</button>
 </p>
 <div id="output">
  
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code.

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyStae == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)){
            callback(xhr.responseXML);
        }
}
```

It should be `xhr.readyState == 4`, not `xhr.readyStae == 4`.

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)){
            callback(xhr.responseXML);
        }
}
```

Comment: @HTACESSsha-5 No problem.